# Align left div vertically on middle of right div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I made an "arrow" with a div on the left side of another (right) div. Both are inside a container div. I'm trying to align it at the middle of the parent (thus staying aligned at the middle of the right div) with

```
top: 50%;
```

...But it isn't aligning exactly at the middle. It can be set with "margin-top" but i don't want a fixed value.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhofmgbb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
top: calc(50% - 4px)
```

4px being half of the arrow div diagonal, divided by 2.
sqrt(6 * 2 + 6 * 2) / 2.

Explanation: The arrow div is rotated, the diagonal length is 8.48 px.
You should subtract half of this value for the middle of the container's div height to find the y coordinate relative to the top, for it to be centered.
This won't work in older browsers though.

Comment: So you're saying the msgBoxArrow div adds to the size of the parent div? With absolute positioning shouldn't it be removed the flow and the parent div be the height of the msgBoxText div?

Comment: top: 50% means the top of your element will be positioned at the 50% point. You need the middle of your element to be placed at the 50% point.